# Spring Boot console color

Tags: java, spring-boot, colors, configuration, console

When i run the springboot application i get the console log color in red. I have tried to change the colors by adding`spring.output.ansi.enabled=always` in the `application.properties` and added a `logback.xml` file as well, but it didn't work.
this is my `logback.xml` file:

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

this is the console color
[image]

what did i miss? any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

When you add `logback.xml` is not enough just to set `spring.output.ansi.enabled=ALWAYS` but also need to use the %clr conversion word in your logging pattern. Example, if the logging pattern was previously `logging.pattern.console=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level - %msg%n` now it could instead be entirely colored as `logging.pattern.console=%clr(%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level - %msg%n)` or to color just the log-level in console `logging.pattern.console=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} $clr(%-5level) - %msg%n`

Here is example of `logback.xml` file that will give colored output:

```
<configuration debug="true">
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
<!-- On Windows machines setting withJansi to true enables ANSI
        color code interpretation by the Jansi library. This requires
        org.fusesource.jansi:jansi:1.8 on the class path.  Note that
        Unix-based operating systems such as Linux and Mac OS X
        support ANSI color codes by default. -->
<withJansi>true</withJansi>
<encoder>
<pattern>[%thread] %highlight(%-5level) %cyan(%logger{15}) - %msg %n</pattern>
</encoder>
</appender>
<root level="DEBUG">
<appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
</root>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Hi, just tried it but it yet didn't work, could the problem be somewhere in the configuration ?

Comment: Which version of spring boot are you using? Do you use intelij and which version? Try to add: logging.pattern.console= %d{yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %highlight(%-5level) %cyan(%logger{15}) - %msg %n  in application.properties

Comment: Springboot is 2.6.6, IntelliJ IDEA 2022.1.2 (Ultimate Edition). I have tried to add ```logging.pattern.console= %d{yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %highlight(%-5level) %cyan(%logger{15}) - %msg %n``` in the application.properties. But it didn't work

Comment: That is weird. Did you try without logback.xml file?

Comment: i tried with and without, but it is still not working.

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: I am using windows